# My router doesn't work anymore

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an **Asus RT-N13U B1** router and it doesn't work anymore and here what I have noticed so far:

- The power LED is solid for 4 seconds then goes off (and the LAN led too if
  connected) it seems that the device reboots itself every 4 seconds!
- I can't access it via the web interface.
- Of course wifi is not working
- The router is unreachable by ssh
- The router is unreachable by telnet
- The router is unreachable by ping
- Nmap can't see the router
- LAN is only working in restore (recovery) mode (doesn't hang up)
- I can update the firmware via Ethernet cable in restoration mode with the "Asus firmware restoration tool" which says:

> firmware update success... wait for reboot

Then the device reboots itself every 4 seconds even after I manually plug / unplug the device

- I have tried the 30/30/30 nvram clearing method but it didn't work
- I have tried many firmwares so far but none works

Any suggestions please?

Comment: sounds like you know your router, and it's gone, alternatively try calling asus who will likely tell you it's gone.

Comment: Yeah, I second what @barlop said. That's an old-ass router and it died. N300 is from 2007. Time to advance to the 2013+ era and buy a 3-4 stream 802.11ac, simultaneous dual-band router. Consider a Google OnHub.